# Javascript - Are there any difference writing the property name inside quote and direct?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I see some of the code in my application has the following way of creating objects,

```
let request = {
  'name' : this.form.value.name
};
```

I prefer giving the property name without quotes like,

```
let request = {
 name : this.form.value.name
}
```

Which is proper and are there any differences?

Comment: You can have spaces in the name when you use quote.

Comment: No difference. You can use quotes if you use characters that are not allowed in bare property names: `{"my-key": "value"}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless an object key is a numeric literal or a valid identifier name, you need to quote it to avoid a syntax error from being thrown. In other words, quotes can only be omitted if the property name is a numeric literal or a valid identifier name. Of course, if the property name is a string literal, it’s already quoted by definition.

```
var object = {
// `abc` is a valid identifier; no quotes are needed
abc: 1,
// `123` is a numeric literal; no quotes are needed
123: 2,
// `012` is an octal literal with value `10` and thus isn’t allowed in strict mode; but if you insist on using it, quotes aren’t needed
012: 3,
// `π` is a valid identifier; no quotes are needed
π: Math.PI,
// `var` is a valid identifier name (although it’s a reserved word); no quotes are needed
var: 4,
// `foo bar` is not a valid identifier name; quotes are required
'foo bar': 5,
// `foo-bar` is not a valid identifier name; quotes are required
'foo-bar': 6,
// the empty string is not a valid identifier name; quotes are required
'': 7 };
```

For more reference please see [here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-properties)

Answer (score 1):

Quotes is not mandatory in javascript. There is a bit of difference though

- You need quotes to support spaces in key

  {
       "space key": 2
  }
- You need quotes for key that is a reserved javascript keyword (ES6 allows reserved keywords)

  {
       "this": 2
  }

Comment: #2 is obsoleted, you can use a keyword as a property name without quotes in ES6.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the code that you've provided but in general Yes there is a difference.

If the property name is valid identifier then there is no need for quotes else you need quotes.

[Valid identifier](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Identifier) in JavaScript

If you don't wrap key which is not a valid identifier you will get `unexpected identifier` syntax error as shown in below snippet.

```js
let request = {
  'name': 'with quotes',
  'key code': 'with quotes',
};
let request1 = {
  name: 'without quotes',
  key code: 'with quotes',
};
console.log(request);
console.log(request1);
```